# Change file extension SPListItem SharePoint 2007

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow, workflow-activity

I've Forms Library in SharePoint 2007. I've created a custom workflow activity that makes it possible to convert InfoPath documents to PDF. But when I try to replace original InfoPath file to the new PDF file it keeps referencing to the InfoPath file. How can I rename the InfoPath list item to PDF?

It can't be changed manually (it's a requirement to be automatically). My only problem now is that I need to store the PDF file in the same SPListItem. Because I want to keep the metadata and history information of the file (requirement).

My code:

```
//new url = file.pdf
//old url = file.xml
//pdf doc = byte[] of pdf file

file.MoveTo(newUrl);
file.ReplaceLink(oldUrl, newUrl);
file.SaveBinary(pdfdoc);

file.Update();
file.CheckIn("File Converted to PDF - V1.0");
file.Update();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by creating a new SPListItem for the PDF file. Then after that I copy the content of every field to the new SPListItem. And after that you can delete the old file or archive it for later use.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the *FileLeafRef* field of the `SPListItem` in order to rename a `SPFile`:

```
file.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.FileLeafRef] = newUrl;
// UpdateOverwriteVersion() in order to prevent duplicated version histroy entries...
file.Item.UpdateOverwriteVersion(); 

file.SaveBinary(pdfDoc);
```

Comment: Does this also update the other fields? Like: EncodedAbsUrl (Encoded absolute url) etc?

Comment: Yes, the _EncodedAbsUrl_ field, `SPFile.Name`, etc. will be updated.

Comment: When I try your code the Field FileLeafRef stays the same: Field: FileLeafRef value: 25. Form.xml

Comment: I tried something else: When changing the file name from file.xml to file2.xml it works. But when I try to change from file.xml to file.pdf it doesn't work.